# SendAsync and CopyToAsync not working when downloading a large file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, reverse-proxy

I have a small app that receives a request from a browser, copy the header received and the post data (or GET path) and send it to another endpoint.

It then waits for the result and sends it back to the browser. It works like a reverse proxy.

Everything works fine until it receives a request to download a large file. Something like a 30MB will cause an strange behaviour in the browser. When the browser reaches around 8MB it stops receiving data from my app and, after some time, it aborts the download. Everything else works just fine.

If I change the `SendAsync` line to use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` it works just fine. I am assuming there is something wrong waiting for the stream and/or task, but I can't figure out what is going on.

The application is written in C#, .net Core (latest version available).

Here is the code (partial)

```
private async Task SendHTTPResponse(HttpContext context, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode;

    foreach (var header in responseMessage.Headers)
    {
        context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
    }

    foreach (var header in responseMessage.Content.Headers)
    {
        context.Response.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();
    }

    context.Response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");

    using (var responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
       await responseStream.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
    }

}

public async Task ForwardRequestAsync(string toHost, HttpContext context)
{

    var requestMessage = this.BuildHTTPRequestMessage(context);
    var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted);
    await this.SendHTTPResponse(context, responseMessage);
}
```

**EDIT**

Changed the SendHTTPResponse to wait for `responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` using await operator.

Comment: You're blocking on reading the stream, for one, which could very likely cause a deadlock. I'm not sure why you're handling this differently, when you're properly awaiting in other places.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean @ChrisPratt? I cannot use await in the method responseStream.CopyToAsync because its return type is Task<Stream>

Comment: I'm talking about calling `Wait()`, and then later `Result`, in that method. Add the `async` keyword to the method signature and then `await` your `resultTask`.

Comment: Like that?  using (var responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                await responseStream.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
            }

Comment: @ChrisPratt I changed the code as you pointed out, but it still does not work.

Comment: By definition `ResponseContentRead - The operation should complete after reading the entire response including the content.`, as apposed to `ResponseHeadersRead - The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. The content is not read yet.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to avoid: downloading the entire response content to the memory before sending it to the browser. If I do that, I may end up causing a serious memory issue since this app will be serving a lot of data.

Comment: You are most likely getting a time out when it takes too long for the content to be copied over to the other stream.

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah, but I have no idea where and how to setup de timeout. I have done it in the http client.

Comment: @RafaelColucci can you update the example shown with a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. It would help us investigate the problem while looking for potential solutions. While the *partial* code you have does help, there are too many unknown  variables that would have us guessing what you did which would skew our testing.

Comment: How long does it take from start of request in the browser until the browser stalls? Is it always the same or nearly the same time, and if yes what? Knowing this would help us come up with ideas.

Comment: You have surely not posted the complete code, as parts of code are not compiling, but from your question it is not clear, why you cannot use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead`, while using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` it is clear that `responseMessage` is considered completed moment header are read, which can easily mean skipping the full content. Also what kind of Cancellation token  is `context.RequestAborted` and what kind of stream is `context.Response.Body`. Would be tough to answer, without getting a complete picture.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess but I believe the issue lies with the removal of the transfer encoding:

```
context.Response.Headers.Remove("transfer-encoding");
```

If the http request you are making with `_httpClient` returns the 30MB file using **Chunked** encoding (target server doesn't know the file size) then you would need to return the file to the browser with **Chunked** encoding as well.

When you buffer the response on your webservice (by passing `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead`) you know the exact message size you are sending back to the browser so the response works successfully.

I would check the response headers you get from `responseMessage` to see if the transfer encoding is chunked.

Comment: I have checked it already, there is no transfer encoding in the response I get from the server. I also tried returning the task and it did not work :(

Comment: Instead of calling your webservice from the browser, can you try writing a console app to call your webservice? That way you know the browser isn't doing anything funky. You could share client side and server side exception messages with us which would help.

Comment: I don't think this will compile if you try to return a Task while also awaiting in the async function. So your final suggestion should be reviewed.

Comment: You should be able to fix the example if you just `await` that final call rather the `return`ing it.

Comment: Great answer. Worked for a guy trying to piece together a reverse proxy in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to stream a file but you are doing it not exactly right. If you do not specify,`ResponseHeadersRead`, response will never come back unless the server ends the request because it will try to read the response till the end.
HttpCompletionOption enumeration type has two members and one of them is ResponseHeadersRead which tells the HttpClient to only read the headers and then return back the result immediately.

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) { 
        //Oh baby we are streaming
        //Do stuff copy to response stream etc..
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what OP is doing `responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`, then Copy to the stream, what is different about your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Figure 3 shows a simple example where one method blocks on the result of an async method. This code will work just fine in a console application but will deadlock when called from a GUI or ASP.NET context. This behavior can be confusing, especially considering that stepping through the debugger implies that it’s the await that never completes. The actual cause of the deadlock is further up the call stack when Task.Wait is called.

Figure 3 A Common Deadlock Problem When Blocking on Async Code

```
public static class DeadlockDemo
{
  private static async Task DelayAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
  // This method causes a deadlock when called in a GUI or ASP.NET context.
  public static void Test()
  {
    // Start the delay.
    var delayTask = DelayAsync();
    // Wait for the delay to complete.
    delayTask.Wait();
  }
}
```

The root cause of this deadlock is due to the way await handles contexts. By default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task completes. This “context” is the current SynchronizationContext unless it’s null, in which case it’s the current TaskScheduler. GUI and ASP.NET applications have a SynchronizationContext that permits only one chunk of code to run at a time. When the await completes, it attempts to execute the remainder of the async method within the captured context. But that context already has a thread in it, which is (synchronously) waiting for the async method to complete. They’re each waiting for the other, causing a deadlock.

Note that console applications don’t cause this deadlock. They have a thread pool SynchronizationContext instead of a one-chunk-at-a-time SynchronizationContext, so when the await completes, it schedules the remainder of the async method on a thread pool thread. The method is able to complete, which completes its returned task, and there’s no deadlock. This difference in behavior can be confusing when programmers write a test console program, observe the partially async code work as expected, and then move the same code into a GUI or ASP.NET application, where it deadlocks.

The best solution to this problem is to allow async code to grow naturally through the codebase. If you follow this solution, you’ll see async code expand to its entry point, usually an event handler or controller action. Console applications can’t follow this solution fully because the Main method can’t be async. If the Main method were async, it could return before it completed, causing the program to end. Figure 4 demonstrates this exception to the guideline: The Main method for a console application is one of the few situations where code may block on an asynchronous method.

Figure 4 The Main Method May Call Task.Wait or Task.Result

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    MainAsync().Wait();
  }
  static async Task MainAsync()
  {
    try
    {
      // Asynchronous implementation.
      await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Handle exceptions.
    }
  }
}
```

[LEARN MORE HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score -4):

try these.

```
using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage= await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    await this.SendHTTPResponse(context, responseMessage);
}
```

or

```
using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage=await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage,
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted))
{
    await this.SendHTTPResponse(context, responseMessage)
}
```